# Can I make 'get_absolute_url' return a related modal DetailView?

Tags: python, django

So I have a Django project that includes a model named 'Artist'. I've created the detail view showing all the variables associated with this model (yay!) Now I want to include a comment feature for each artist, so I've created a model named 'ArtistComment':

```
class ArtistComment(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
     artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='artistcomment')
     message = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)

     def approve(self):
         self.approved_comment = True
         self.save()

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('events:artistdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

     def __str__(self):
         return self.created_at.strftime('%H: %M - %d %b')
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
    url(r'^artist-(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.ArtistDetailView.as_view()), name='artistdetail'),
    url(r'^artistcomment/add/$', login_required(views.ArtistCommentCreate.as_view()), name='artistcomment-add'),
```

My ArtistComment CreateView looks like this:

```
class ArtistCommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = ArtistComment
    fields = ['artist', 'message',]

    def form_valid(self, form, **args):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

And finally the URL in the ArtistDetail view looks like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#artistcommentModal" href="{% url 'events:artistcomment-add' %}">Add A New Comment</a></p>
```

(I'm using a modal div to make the form pop-up)

My issue is that when I submit a new comment the 'get_absolute_url' returns the Primary Key from the ArtistComment, rather than the Artist the ArtistComment is related to. How would I make the form redirect to the Artist page it just submitted a comment to?

I also looked into adding a success_url to the CreateView, but I ran into similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the primary key of the related artist, you would use `self.artist_id` or `self.artist.pk` instead of `self.pk`

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('events:artistdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.artist_id})
```

However, it might not be a good idea to make the `get_absolute_url` for a `ArtistComment` return a url for a different model. An alternative would be to override `get_success_url` in the view instead.

```
class ArtistCommentCreate(CreateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events:artistdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.artist_id})
```

Note that `CreateView`'s `form_valid()` method will take care of saving the form when you call `super()`,  so you can remove the `self.object = form.save()` line.

```
    def form_valid(self, form, **args):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(ArtistCommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

You may want to use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to prevent anonymous users from being able to create comments.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Extra thanks for the tip on calling super()